# Mobile first and semantic document outline

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a site that's built mobile first. I've a number of components that change depending on the screen size. For example, at mobile screen sizes I have an accordion that switches to a tab bar above 769px.

The document outline displays both components so I end up with -
h1 - document title
  h2 - component 1 (the mobile version)
  h2 - component 1 (the Desk top version)

What's the best way to display on the visible (active) component in the document outline whilst hiding the hidden (inactive) component?

Comment: A pen can be seen here: http://s.codepen.io/sharperwebdev/debug/vNEpOm?  If you use h5o or similar to view the doc outline you can see the heading set to display none is still seen in the document outline.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display: none` for whichever is inactive in your media queries, hiding anything that isn't supposed to be shown.

Comment: Yes thats what I thought, but it's still displaying the header in the document outline.

Comment: Could you provide some code/create a JSFiddle so we can better understand and replicate the problem please?